# Android - Adding RadioButton into RadioGroup dynamically

Tags: android

I am trying to add radiobutton dynamically into radiogroup, but i cannot add the radiobutton into it. (it shows no radiobutton inside the radiogroup)
the code shows no error.

I have been searching the solution since this morning.
Thanks a lot for the help!!

```
private void createCustomDialog(){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose Device");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_choose_device);

        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutCD);

        LinearLayout li = new LinearLayout(this);
        li.setLayoutParams(params);
        li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



        RadioGroup rg =  (RadioGroup)dialog.findViewById(R.id.rgCD);
        RadioButton[] rbArray = new RadioButton[bdList.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < bdList.size(); i++){
            rbArray[i] = new RadioButton(this);
            rbArray[i].setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rbArray[i].setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            rbArray[i].setText(bdList.get(i).getName());
            rbArray[i].setId(i);
            Log.d(LOG, "" + bdList.get(i).getName());
            li.addView(rbArray[i]);

        }

        Button btnOK = new Button(this);


        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    ((ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rgCD)).addView(li);

    dialog.show();
}
```

my xml file for dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCD"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgCD"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);

RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
radioButton.setText("radio text");
radioButton.setId(1234);//set radiobutton id and store it somewhere
RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rg.addView(radioButton, params);
```

Comment: The problem fixed by this answer is that you need to add the RadioButtons to the RadioGroup, not to the LinearLayout.

Comment: BTW when I tried this technique, the RadioGroup's "multiple-exclusion scope" didn't work. In other words, when I checked a second radio button, the first one should have been cleared but it stayed checked.